# In Unix, how to create a file in a absolute path name

Tags: shell, unix

my variable `path1` contains the value `/home/folder`. how can I create a new file named `foo` using this absolute path name?

```
path1="/home/folder"
echo "hello web" > $path1/foo
```

but this code give me error. Can some one please tell me how can I create this file foo in a specific location, using a path name?

Comment: What error? Probably the directory doesn't exist or you don't have write permission.

Comment: when i type in ls -l, it shows every folder has rw permissions. error i get is "bash: /home/Downloads/foo: No such file or directory". but if I type in $HOME/folder/foo instead of /home/folder/foo it works.

Comment: If you do 'echo $HOME' you will probably find out that $HOME is NOT /home but rather something like /home/username .

Comment: Thanks for all the input and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash you should write:

```
path1="/home/folder"; echo "hello web" > $path1/foo
```

Or:

```
export path1="/home/folder"
echo "hello web" > $path1/foo
```

Notation you used works only in bash script.

Comment: I do not think that the first version will work, unless you have a semicolon before echo. As it is, path1 will be exported to echo, but it will not be expanded with the correct value in the redirection.